# Show Columns in Highcharts on different X-Axis (side by side)

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I've tried to add multiple series to different X-Axis on a column chart. My problem is, that Highcharts reserve space for each column series, but in my case the series are uniqe to one X-Axis and they are not overlapping. So I don't want to reserve space for columns that are never appear in the group.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Kanatorabo/qs0vuehk/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: 'Columns centered in category'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Null or missing points are ignored'
},

xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    offset: 0,
    left: "20%",
    width: "80%",
}, {
    categories: ['2018', '2019', '2020'],
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    offset: 0,
    width: "20%",
}],

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        centerInCategory: true,
        //pointPadding: 0,
    },
    /*column: {
        grouping: false,
        shadow: false,
        pointPadding: 0.2,
    }*/
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, null, null, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    name: "data1",
}, {
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
    name: "data2",
}, {
    data: [71.5, 106.4, 129.2, null, null, 135.6, 148.5, null, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9],
    name: "data3",
}, {
    data: [null, 70.5, 99.4],
    colorIndex: 0,
    name: "data1 preVal",
    linkedTo: 0,
    xAxis: 1,
}, {
    data: [null, 60.5, 89.4],
    name: "data2 preVal",
    colorIndex: 1,
    linkedTo: 1,
    xAxis: 1,
}, {
    data: [null, 80.5, 69.4],
    colorIndex: 2,
    name: "data3 preVal",
    linkedTo: 2,
    xAxis: 1,
}]
```

});

In 2019/2020 and Feb/Mar there is a reserved space for 6 columns and the width of all columns is calculated as if 6 columns exists.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug, I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15503